# R.Java errors, and more

Tags: android, eclipse

I am really annoyed and frustrated by the fact that I'm getting all kinds of errors out of nothing. My entire application is as good as finished, and now without changing anything, I get these random errors. I'm using eclipse, which is a big mistake. The first error is `"R cannot be resolved to a variable"`

Now I had this before, and I looked solutions up for this, but literally everything I tried didn't work. Then next to this error, I have the following error, in my Manifest file: `error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/title_activity_main').`

Now the name of that string/title activity main is the same in every single file, I have no clue what the error means or how I can fix it.

Last error, which takes place in my `styles_base.xml`, which isn't even in my project file, but in the `android-support-v7-appcompat` file:

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
```

Now I seriously don't have any clues how this happened, why this happened, or how I can fix it, and it's driving me crazy. Can someone help me with this, and please stay with me for it. Because I've searched this question, and out of like 50 solutions, none worked for me. So please stay with me throughout the process. Would be very appreciated. If I need to add any parts of my code, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

when I got errors in my project,I will first to clean the project.If it didn't work,I would see the Console to see what's the problem.If it still didn't work,I will see the Problem panel,where there will list all the error,I just read carefully and you will know the trouble.
Of course,I have to see the preference of the project.

Comment: Cleaned it over 100 times, checked console over 100 times, the error just doesn't make any sense and I totally don't get it

Comment: Maybe you should see the SDK of your project now

Comment: Do you import other .jar file?

Comment: Maybe it because the .jar file you import contains the `android-support-v7-appcompat` which is different from the `android-support-v7-appcompat` you wanna import really,so the the system don't know use which one.